# how to show Custom Created field in sugarcrm module edit view

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new learner of sugarcrm. I have created a custom field in accounts module. Now I want to show that custom created field in account module edit view. Can anyone help me. Thank you

Comment: Version number, and CRM tier would certainly be helpful. I take it you created the field in the studio?

Comment: You just need to drag and drop your new field in edit view panel through studio.

Comment: if you want it via  code, edit the modules vardef and in editviewdefs.php of your module, add the new field, try to repair and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is through Studio.  Do the following:

1. Go to Studio
2. Go to the Accounts module
3. Go to Layouts
4. Go to "Record View"
5. Find "New Row" in the toolbox on the left
6. Drag that box to the panel where you want the new custom field to appear, and drop it there
7. You should see two "(filler)" fields now
8. Find your custom field in the toolbox on the left
9. Drag your field and drop it into one of the "(filler)" boxes
10. You should now see it next to the other "(filler)" box
11. Click on the "Save & Deploy" button
12. Your field should now appear on the detail and edit views.

Comment: What will be the procedure when we trying to do the same above using module loader?

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this question?  There are ways to do this through code and not through Studio.  Is that what you were after?